# How to pull history data which was loaded before snowflake stream

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having a table called Table-A and it’s a raw data table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcT9D.jpg)

Table-A

EMPID   ENAME   SAL REC_CREATED

101 ABC 100 20-11-2021 02:20

102 DEF 125 21-11-2021 10:35

After 2 records, requirement changed, and I have created the stream on Table-A to load them into my Target table which is Table-B.

Is there a way I can pull the previous 2 records (history) from Table-A to insert them into Table-B as stream will pull only new records (empid 103 onwards) from Table-A.? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not with Streams, you can do it manually, but I feel that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, i am looking for permanent fix, what if stream breaks in prod and want to pull history again

Answer (score 0):

You could query Table A with an offset so the results returned will be how it looked at that time. So for example, the below will return what it looked like 5 mins ago

```
select * from table_a at(offset => -60*5);
```

Another trick I discovered was to be able to store all data that was previously in a stream, without consuming the data. So you could do something like the below before consuming your stream data

```
SELECT * FROM my_stream;
INSERT INTO my_table select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id()));
```

You could also setup a second stream on Table A that only gets consumed when you need to see the previous data